# Parse WKT strings to get array of points

Tags: javascript, turfjs, wkt

```
POLYGON ((162353.9901277053 564298.9605047705,162352.3101277038 564286.9905047683, 162353.9901277053 564298.9605047705))
```

output need

```
[[162353.9901277053, 564298.9605047705], [162352.3101277038, 564286.9905047683],[ 162353.9901277053, 564298.9605047705]]
```

I've been looking at Turf,unfortunately not found

Comment: Did you try https://terraformer.io/wkt-parser/ ?

Comment: thanks..@ peeeebeee ..yes i have tried

Comment: Since there's the `leaflet` tag, I'm gonna say https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore . Still, the question is not worded as a question, so please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @BKS any comment on my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Terraformer.WKT.parse` to convert WKT POLYGON to GeoJSON, then get the coordinates out of it. Here is the runnable code.

```js
// Use Terraformer.WKT.parse() to convert WKT to GeoJSON

var geojson_pgons = Terraformer.WKT.parse('POLYGON ((162353.9901277053 564298.9605047705,162352.3101277038 564286.9905047683, 162353.9901277053 564298.9605047705))');

// get coordinates list of the first object
var poly0xys = geojson_pgons.coordinates[0];

// collect what we need
var result = [];
for (let i=0; i<poly0xys.length; i++) {
    //console.log( poly0xys[i] );
    result.push(  poly0xys[i] );
}

console.log( result );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer@1.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer-wkt-parser@1.1.2"></script>
```